# How to increase height of Bootstrap select dropdown options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to increase the height of Bootstrap select dropdown options. Is it possible to set a custom height for the option element?

[image]

My HTML code,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Color</label> 
      <select class="form-control">
          <option value="r">Red</option>
          <option value="b">Blue</option>
          <option value="g">Green</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of a html "select"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my requirement and hope this could help to others. [This plugin](https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select) allows defining the height for the select options.